# pod install error>>> [!] Unable to determine the platform for the `AdewoleFarmApp` target

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, cocoapods, aws-sdk

I downloaded github amplify.swift, created Podfile per installation instruction,
but Cocoapods "pod install" gets the error.

Podfile is:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'AdewoleFarmApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for AdewoleFarmApp
    pod 'Amplify'
    pod 'AmplifyPlugins/AWSCognitoAuthPlugin'
    pod 'AWSPredictionsPlugin'
    pod 'CoreMLPredictionsPlugin'

end
```

and below is the error i was getting when i ran pod install:
[image: my Pod Error]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try uncommenting (remove the #) the second line of the podfile. I guess the platform declaration is not working since it is commented out